# how to compare each element in array?

Tags: java, jsonpath

```json
{
  "store": {
    "book": [
      {
        "category": "reference",
        "author": "Nigel Rees",
        "title": "Sayings of the Century",
        "price": 8.95
      },
      {
        "category": "fiction",
        "author": "Evelyn Waugh",
        "title": "Sword of Honour",
        "price": 12.99
      },
      {
        "category": "fiction",
        "author": "Herman Melville",
        "title": "Moby Dick",
        "isbn": "0-553-21311-3",
        "price": 8.99
      },
      {
        "category": "fiction",
        "author": "J. R. R. Tolkien",
        "title": "The Lord of the Rings",
        "isbn": "0-395-19395-8",
        "price": 22.99
      }
    ]
  }
}
```

The following is my case:
author=='Nigel Rees'.price < author=='Evelyn Waugh'.price

My query expression: `$.store.book[?($.store.book[?(@.author == 'Nigel Rees')].price < $.store.book[?(@.author == 'Evelyn Waugh')].price)]`

I hope it will return the following result:

```
{
    "category": "reference",
    "author": "Nigel Rees",
    "title": "Sayings of the Century",
    "price": 8.95
}
```

What is the correct expression?

Answer (score 0):

Ordinarily, to iterate over the items in an array and perform a comparison, you'd need to use a filter selector:

```
$.store.books[?(@.price<12.99)]
```

But this doesn't allow you to compare items against each other.  Within that expression, you should (may depend on the library you're using) be able to use the `$` to refer back to the JSON root.  This would allow you to make a comparison against a particular item:

```
$.store.books[?(@.price<$.store.books[1].price)]
```

This compares all of the book prices against the price of the second book in the array.  I think this is the closest you're going to get with JSON Path.

---

We're currently working on a [specification for JSON Path](https://github.com/ietf-wg-jsonpath/draft-ietf-jsonpath-base) to define an official syntax and feature set.  Feel free to open an issue (and link to this question) to request "multiple iterator" support so that items can be compared against each other.